# Did Adam and Eve meet at Mount Arafat?

Tags: source-identification, adam-and-eve

I hear a persistent rumor that [Adam and Eve met on Mount Arafat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Arafat).

> According to Islamic tradition, it was on Mount Arafah that Adam and Eve, separated for 200 years following their expulsion from the Garden of Eden, met and recognized each other and were reunited

Is there anything backing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar account in Jewish traditions, where Adam and Eve are separated for 130 years (not 200) after they are expelled from the Garden.  This is reflected (but not explicit) in the Biblical record by the 130-year gap between the birth of Cain/Abel and the later birth of Seth.

However, I know no references as to where they eventually reunited, be it Arafah or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Quran mentions that both Adam and Eve (PBUT) were both deceived by [Satan](http://quran.com/2/36) and both of them were sent down to [earth](http://quran.com/2/38). Although it does not disprove that they were separated, but there is no indication to show that they were, too. My personal inclination is that they were not, unless there is some hadith otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

According to Islamic sources, there is no such mention of such incident that where did they met. So as we do not have any prof from Authentic sources of Islam, then we should not care about whether they were separated or not. As its just not our concern. The knowledge about them, given to us , from Quran and hadith is more than enough for us to know, beyond that even if someone wants to go, then its not recommended according to islamic source